# Change AndroidManifest.xml MetaData Value in Unity Project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I have a Unity project. One of the libraries that I use in my project has metadata in its Manifest file. Is there any way to keep change its value?
When I add my value in the AndroidManifest.xml file remained the old value.

```
<meta-data
        android:name='MetaDataName'
        android:value='oldValue' />

<meta-data
        android:name='MetaDataName'
        android:value='newValue' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your manifest

```
<meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name='MetaDataName'
        android:value='newValue' />
```

Comment: It Doesn't work. This error occurred in Android Studio: Attribute tools:replace is not allowed here

Comment: Do you have tools added as namespace like this  ` xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ` in your manifest tag ?

Comment: Yes I have this line in my manifest tag: xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: Yeah, it works! I should add these codes to the custom main manifest. Thanks.

Comment: @BehroozFard I'm glad if I was of any help, can you please upvote as well. Thanks